# ActionMailer not returning full from address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I'm using ActionMailer and in a test I'm trying to verify that the correct from address has been set. However when I use a from address with a sender name, I only get the email address back when calling `#from` I need to check the whole thing. I've tried checking `#sender`, but that is nil

Example:

```
msg1 = ActionMailer::Base::mail(:from => "sender name <test@example.com>").from
=> ["test@example.com"]
```

If I `to_s` the object, it does seem to use the full email including sender name:

```
msg1.to_s
=> "Date: Fri, 20 Jun 2014 11:14:53 +0000\r\nFrom: sender name    <test@example.com>\r\nMessage-ID: <XXXX>\r\nSubject: Mail\r\nMime-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: text/plain;\r\n charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n"
```

How do I verify that the from address (including sender name) has been set correctly?

Comment: you can use regex in this case, check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially I used regular expressions as described by singhshivam.

However after a bit a research a colleague suggested you can do this:

`msg1.header[:from].to_s`

I felt this was a better solution as it allowed me to use `assert_equal` rather than `assert_match` so the intention was clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I may not correctly understand your question, however if I guess correctly you can get infos like this:

```
msg1 = ActionMailer::Base::mail(:from => "sender name <test@example.com>")

msg1.from
=> ["test@example.com"]

msg1.date
=> Fri, 20 Jun 2014 18:58:38 +0530

msg1.message_id
=> "53a43706753f4_49053fb4eba3f9b43008a@shivam.mail"

msg1.message_content_type
=> "text/plain"

msg1.main_type
=> "text"

msg1.subject
=> "Mail"
```

Also you can simply type `msg1.` and hit `<tab>` twice. Terminal will ask `Display all 293 possibilities? (y or n)` press y and you can see all the information you can extract from this particular option.

**EDIT**

I guess I understand the question better now and did some research. The way you are entering the sender name, it seems that you cannot retrieve it directly. However, we may use regex in this case. Here the code, I know its (extremely) dirty, but it works nonetheless:

```
pat = "(?<=From:)(.*)(?=<#{msg1.from.to_s})"
/#{pat}/.match(msg1.inspect)[0].strip
```

Comment: can you please verify this @Ceri ? Thanks

Comment: Thanks - I did use a regular expression match initially, but a colleague suggested a better way in the end that made the intention clearer.